# How can one open a file from a directory window into an existing window?

Tags: vim-windows

In a directory window (:Explore or :Vexplore) every 'o' or 'v' creates a new window, I just want 1 directory view window on the left and 1 file view window on the right like a classic IDE. When opening a file, how do I open it in the right window that already exists?

Thank you!

Comment: That was me. I just corrected myself. :) This is related info: [Replace netrw window when opening a file](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/19917)/   (I'm not sure if it qualifies as a duplicate even though it has all the relevant info in it.)

Comment: I decided duping this didn't make sense even though I was able to reuse some of my answer there in the new answer below.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @BogdanBalan You left before my comment became an answer. If/when you come back please vote/accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Two things are needed. First you need to change `g:netrw_browse_split`. Here's the help for that setting:

```
  *g:netrw_browse_split*    when browsing, <cr> will open the file by:
                =0: re-using the same window  (default)
                =1: horizontally splitting the window first
                =2: vertically   splitting the window first
                =3: open file in new tab
                =4: act like "P" (ie. open previous window)
```

"Open previous window" is what we want so

```
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
```

Then you just need to press the right key when the cursor is over the file you want to open. The help excerpt also gives us that information (`<cr> will open the file by`...).

So, not <kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>V</kbd> but <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That should do it.

Note: Per the help on the line about value `4` the approach I use above is "like" pressing `P`. When I tried `P` it didn't work as expected so I chose an approach which *did* work. To be fair, my netrw configuration is not default so you may want to try `P` for yourself (without changing the variable from `0`).

Comment: Would pressing P just work with no hassle though ?

Comment: Not for me though I have non-defaults for various settings. I've not spent any time looking into it, but why would they have the above setting if it weren't necessary due to always having `P` do the same thing?

Comment: Not sure, just noticed that the docs said `act like "P"`

Comment: Yes, pressing `P` for me "just works" (in my vim and in `vim --clean` w/ `:runtime plugin/netrwPlugin.vim`)

Comment: I never doubted it _can_ work. All I  know is when I was writing this it didn't work so I chose what worked (and what I have experience with) and what has documentation explicitly differentiating it from other split modes and what seems more robust based on my having non-default configuration. But I'll mention `P` has a possible alternative.

Comment: Not nitpicking. I can write my own answer if I need to. Re docs, help netrw-P.